# Maven Repository Server - Getting User Name and Password

Tags: maven, gradle, archiva

I have written a basic maven repository with java upon HTTP. That can handle both maven, gradle publish and dependency-request.  I used *Embeded jetty and Servlet* to handle the request.

Now as like original repo or archiva, they some time need userName and password for publishing or getting artifact. The user name and password we provide into **setings.xml** for maven and in **credential** block in gradle.

Now i need those credential from my basic server. But i couldn't find it in the header or Authentication header. How Can i Get those credential?

**Update::::  I can solve this problem if i can send some extra header with gradle. How can i do that?**

Comment: I'd install a proxy that intercepts every connection to internet, then I'd inspect every call and would try to figure out how are the credentials sent.

Comment: i did something similar  too. ok i am trying again. any suggestion will be appreciated.